# Converting time zones within time series

Tags: r, time, timezone, time-series, timezone-offset

I brought in a time series into R using the parse_date_time function in the library(lubridate) and I brought it in as EST.

```
streamflowDateTime<-parse_date_time(streamflowDateTime,"%m%d%Y %H%M",tz="EST")
```

However, the data experiences DST on 04-03-2005 01:45 and the next time step is 03:00. I want to convert this occurrence and all the time stamps that follow to EST by subtracting an hour so that it is continuous. It would be preferred if there was an automated way to do it where the program figures out where DST starts taking place and moves back an hour itself, since DST does not take effect every year on the same day at the same time.

Here's a sample of the data

```
structure(c(1112475600, 1112476500, 1112477400, 1112478300, 1112479200, 
1112480100, 1112481000, 1112481900, 1112482800, 1112483700, 1112484600, 
1112485500, 1112486400, 1112487300, 1112488200, 1112489100, 1112490000, 
1112490900, 1112491800, 1112492700, 1112493600, 1112494500, 1112495400, 
1112496300, 1112497200, 1112498100, 1112499000, 1112499900, 1112500800, 
1112501700, 1112502600, 1112503500, 1112504400, 1112505300, 1112506200, 
1112507100, 1112508000, 1112508900, 1112509800, 1112510700, 1112515200, 
1112516100, 1112517000, 1112517900, 1112518800, 1112519700, 1112520600, 
1112521500, 1112522400, 1112523300, 1112524200, 1112525100, 1112526000, 
1112526900, 1112527800, 1112528700, 1112529600, 1112530500, 1112531400, 
1112532300, 1112533200, 1112534100, 1112535000, 1112535900, 1112536800, 
1112537700, 1112538600, 1112539500, 1112540400, 1112541300, 1112542200, 
1112543100, 1112544000, 1112544900, 1112545800, 1112546700, 1112547600, 
1112548500, 1112549400, 1112550300, 1112551200, 1112552100, 1112553000, 
1112553900, 1112554800, 1112555700, 1112556600, 1112557500, 1112558400, 
1112559300, 1112560200, 1112561100, 1112562000, 1112562900, 1112563800, 
1112564700, 1112565600, 1112566500, 1112567400, 1112568300, 1112569200
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")
```

Edits:

```
streamflowDateTime[8840:length(streamflowDateTime)] <- streamflowDateTime[8840:length(streamflowDateTime)]-hours(1)
```

In the full entire data set, the occurence happens at location 8840, which I know manually, I want the code to automatically find the position where the time difference between two consecutive time stamps is not 15 minutes and replace the '8840' in code with that automated value. for loops are too slow

Comment: Can you post your raw input `streamflowDateTime` (before calling `parse_Date_time` on it) please?

Comment: That's a data set of length 35034 elements I dont know how I would be able to post that on here

Comment: Also, I read the solution you posted earlier. It doesnt work because it converts the entire data set to EST. Basically, i figured it would help if I brought the data in as EDT and then find the location where DST starts taking place, and convert all the data from that point onwards to EST!

Comment: Just post segment corresponding to the above vector, or at least just a few elements of it. I mainly just need to see the format of the input (character) vector.

Comment: Yes I removed it because I misinterpreted your question. Seeing your original data would help clarify the problem for me.

Comment: The original data class = "factor" and looks like this

Comment: 1      1/1/2005 0:00
2 1/1/2005 0:15
3 1/1/2005 0:30
4 1/1/2005 0:45
5 1/1/2005 1:00
6 1/1/2005 1:15
7 1/1/2005 1:30
8 1/1/2005 1:45
9 1/1/2005 2:00
10 1/1/2005 2:15
11 1/1/2005 2:30
12 1/1/2005 2:45
13 1/1/2005 3:00
14 1/1/2005 3:15
15 1/1/2005 3:30
16 1/1/2005 3:45
17 1/1/2005 4:00

Comment: Also I edited the original post above please read the bottom of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably just supply the full IANA time zone ID `America/New_York` instead of the time zone abbreviation.

```
parse_date_time(streamflowDateTime,"%m%d%Y %H%M",tz="America/New_York")
```

Using `America/New_York` will properly account for both EST and EDT, including the correct transitions between them.

This seems to be supported, as seen [in this blog post](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/03/do-more-with-dates-and-times-in-r-with-lubridate-1-1-0/) - at least on systems that provide IANA/Olson time zones, such as Linux or Mac.

According to [the docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lubridate/docs/tz):

> ... R does not come with a predefined list zone names, but relies on the user's OS to interpret time zone names. As a result, some names will be recognized on some computers but not others. Most computers, however, will recognize names in the timezone data base originally compiled by Arthur Olson. These names normally take the form "Country/City." ...

Since Windows uses its own set of time zones, you will probably not be able to use IANA/Olson identifiers.  However:

- The equivalent Windows time zone id would be `"Eastern Standard Time"`.  (Despite the name, this covers both EST and EDT).  I am uncertain if R supports these or not.
- The fully qualified POSIX time zone for the *current* rule would be  `"EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"`.  This should work on all OS's - however it only represents the US Eastern Time Zone since the 2007 change.

  - From 1987-2006 the rule would have been `"EST5EDT,M4.1.0,M10.5.0"`.  Use the appropriate rule for the values you're working in.  If you have dates that span these periods, you'll need to split them up and process them separately, or if possible, write a function to use the correct rule for the data.

See also, [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: When I try to do this, all the values are converted to NA's and the Console says "Warning in view
All formats failed to parse. No formats found"

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: Updated the answer.  Hopefully that helps.